# How to specify the icon to be displayed by the shell in my application

Tags: mfc, windows-shell

I have a standard MFC application with its own icon, and when viewing the application file through explorer, the icon displays fine. I have to add a library however that also includes icons for its various windows, and when I do add it to the project, Windows Explorer displays one of these icons instead of mine. Is there any way to force explorer displaying a specific icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows displays the first icon in the resource for the program itself, so you just need to make sure that your icon is listed first.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it doesnt work. I have set it to resource ID=1, but it still takes the library's

Comment: It's not the ID that's important, it has to actually be the first icon in the resource table.

Comment: Open your .rc file with a texteditor and put your main icon maually in the first position. And rebuild the project.

Comment: It is of course, but the point is that any icon in the library's .res is shown before my own. I guess when linking the linker puts this .res file before my own, so i need to find out how to put mine first